# Please Help Identify This 2-Pin Connector (Connects a 40mm Fan to a PSU)

Tags: power-supply, identification, connector

Please help me identify what this male connector is. Pictures are attached (both of the male plug and female socket it plugs into). It is from a 40mm fan that plugs into a socket of a PSU of a Surveillance Network Video Recorder.

The 2 pins have a spacing of 2.0mm.

The width of the male plug is 4mm.

I thought it might be a HY2.0mm 2-Pin Connector (looks very similar), but the male plug for this is 5mm in width and hence doesn't fit into the female socket.

Appreciate any assistance you can provide.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like JST PA series.

Male plug photo:
[image]

Female header:
[image]

Datasheet: https://www.jst.co.uk/downloads/series/ePA-F_(21-03-26).pdf

Comment: It certainly does - thank you. Will get hold of one of those and see if it fits.